# How I can use numpy with strings identifier which is point to the user name specific numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy to store the object futures coming from deep learning thread.

I want to make each user has their own numpy array to search. How can I tell Python use this numpy arrays for this user and this for another ?

User also adding new item to the array. I am new to Python.

```
user1 = user1Numpy
user2 = user2Numpy
..
..
```

Comment: You can use a [python dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), a key-value data structure. You can user name as the key and numpy array for that user as the value

Comment: each numpy array for each user is : (13000, 512), so can I put this array directly to dict?

Comment: yes I tried and its cool to use dict with full numpy array. Its very interesting language this python :)